# Foundation 5.1 Off-canvas Not Working on iOS Safari (Simulator)

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

The code below works just fine on a desktop browser (Safari and Firefox) but the menu button does not work with Mobile Safari (when I click nothing happens and I was expecting the menu to show).

I have an old simulator (iOS 5) but Foundation's example code works from their page on the same mobile browser so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. For example, the advanced section in this link works just fine on the same mobile browser: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html and my code is pretty much a copy of theirs.

JS Fiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/rGyKv/

**Update**: Changed the title to off-canvas as opposed to Topbar.

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">

    <link href="/static/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/static/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

    <meta class="foundation-data-attribute-namespace">
    <meta class="foundation-mq-xxlarge">
    <meta class="foundation-mq-xlarge">
    <meta class="foundation-mq-large">
    <meta class="foundation-mq-medium">
    <meta class="foundation-mq-small">

    <script> $(document).ready(function() {$(document).foundation();});</script>

    <meta class="foundation-mq-topbar">

</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns end">
        <div class="off-canvas-wrap docs-wrap">
            <div class="inner-wrap">
                <nav class="tab-bar">
                    <section class="left-small">
                        <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon"> 
                                             <span> </span> </a>
                    </section>
                    <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
                        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
                    </section>
                </nav>
                <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
                    <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                        <li> <label> Welcome </label> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> Logout </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                <section class="main-section">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 columns">
                            <br>
                            <h4 class="">Header</h4>
                            <p> CONTENT GOES HERE</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <a class="exit-off-canvas">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem.  Have you found a better approach to fixing this rather than adding a "dummy" listener to the menu icon?  If I must, I will implement that fix, but if feels very hacky...

Comment: No I used @williem's solution and did not try to find other ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I commented on a thread on the Foundation forums, but haven't heard anything back yet.  It just seems very "dirty" to add an empty listener...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and after some searching I've found a hack by user vietqhoang on Github.

Using the following code to initialise foundation somehow fixed the non-clickable buttons on iOS for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).foundation();

    // Hack to get off-canvas .menu-icon to fire on iOS
    $('.menu-icon').click(function(){ false });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked very well. Updated fiddle for those interested: http://jsfiddle.net/S7a9t/

Comment: This probably saved me a few hours of frustration :) Tranks!

Comment: Good find. I removed the false inside the brackets though, since it seems to be invalid code.

Comment: Wow youre my hero!! Why is this happening?

Comment: It works because it is making the menu-icon clickable in the mobile browser. The actual "proper" solution is to make the HTML properly formed in the first place, and add the href="#" attribute to the anchor <a> tag.

Answer (score 24):

Add the href to this line:

```
<a class="left-off-canvas-toggle" href="#" >
```

This will address the issue for IOS

Comment: This is the correct solution.  The accepted answer fixes the problem by making the tag "clickable" but the real issue is the missing attribute.

Comment: Not only is this the correct solution, it's also the only solution that really works.

Comment: Real solution. Real answer. The accepted answer works as well but that's monkey patching.

Comment: After amending a site with a new OffCanvas menu, I hit this problem immediately. The addition of the href worked for me too.

Comment: This also fixed the same problem for me in mobile Firefox v48.0.